# Prevent autocomplete box from showing up

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I am currently working on a side project and I'm using `dash` in python to create some visualizations. I have a dropdown box for `player name` which plots the data for the respective player. When you enter start entering a players name, the auto complete generated 2 suggestion boxes.

I have tried turning off the autocomplete for dash but thats actually the autocomplete I wanna retain.

Here is my dash code:

```py
    ...,

    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='player_name',
            options=dp.get_clan_player_dropdown_list(),
            placeholder="Select a player to plot",
             ),
    ]),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph'
              ), ...
```

I am getting 2 autocomplete boxes (one over the other). I only expect one. Don't know where the second one is coming from. Maybe its Chrome's default autocomplete that it remembers from before?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following attribute on the input field to disable the HTML autocomplete.

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/input/ set the attribute

autoComplete='off'